# What is this plant with variegated trifoliate leaves?

Tags: identification

This is the first year this plant has shown itself in my yard. I've searched but cannot find any information. I suspect it's a weed or poison species of some sort. It has only three green leaves and then three small burgundy colored leaves folded inward which gives the appearance of a flower.

Does anyone have an idea what it is?

[image]

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found the plant (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Are you in North America? Then it's probably a [*Trillium*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillium), possibly the [Prairie Trillium (*T. recurvatum*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trillium_recurvatum), which has the variegated foliage and reddish blossom that you describe.
It may be protected where you live, so check with your local jurisdiction before you consider removing it.